# JavaScript Drop Down Moving Over Links

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, hover

I got this problem when Im trying to create a javascript dropdown. It keeps moving over my "prices" link but I took off all the padding and margins in the UL. Suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/fSXHj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your hidden ul that is being displayed is widening the outer ul due to its own width.  You need to position your hidden ul as absolute.

Check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/fSXHj/1/

Comment: Ok, further question. Why do people always tell me absolute positioning is bad on different resolutions but it works perfect here? Also thanks !

Comment: Well, it depends on how you're using it.  If you don't specify a top, left, bottom or right (you leave it where it was originally drawn) you won't run into these issues. Also, if you make the parent container position: relative, you can again avoid that issue.  Check out this awesome article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/.